# Interpolation function for single data point

Tags: python-3.x, function, scipy, interpolation, linear-interpolation

I'm using the `interp1d` function for interpolation

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
x = [0, 3, 6, 10, 15, 20]
y = [1.87, 1.76, 1.27, 1.185, 0.995, 0.855]
f = interp1d(x, y, bounds_error=False)

x_find = [0, 5, 8, 10, 28]
print(f(x_find))
```

Using  `bounds_error=False` in `f = interp1d(x, y, bounds_error=False)` returns nan value for x=28 in `x_find`.
Since interp1d raises an error for single datapoints, I tried the following for single datapoint.

```
x0 = [1.87]
y0 = [0.93]
f0 = lambda x: y0[0] if np.isclose(x, x0[0]) else np.NaN
print(f0(x0[0]))
```

This doesn't work when I try `f0(x_find)`.

`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Expected output:
`f0(x_find)` returns nan for values of x in x_find not present in `x0`like how `bounds_error` works.

Suggestions on how to do this will be really helpful

EDIT:

Question:

Would it be possible to modify the interpolation function of the single datapoint so that we could do just f(x_find), something similar to the one returned by f = interp1d() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just only guess that you are missing a very simple thing: to put a single value to the `f0()` function using a list comprehension to get all values in case of a list with values.

Does the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
x = [0, 3, 6, 10, 15, 20]
y = [1.87, 1.76, 1.27, 1.185, 0.995, 0.855]
f = interp1d(x, y, bounds_error=False)

x_find = [0, 5, 8, 10, 28]
print(f(x_find))
x0 = [1.87]
y0 = [0.93]
f0 = lambda x: y0[0] if np.isclose(x, x0[0]) else np.NaN
print(f0(x0[0]))

print([f0(x) for x in x_find])
```

which prints:

```
[1.87       1.43333333 1.2275     1.185             nan]
0.93
[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]
```

meet your expectations?

You can also redefine f0 to cover the case of passing a list of values to it as follows:

```
def f0(x): 
    import numpy as np
    x0 = [1.87]
    y0 = [0.93]
    f = lambda x: y0[0] if np.isclose(x, x0[0]) else np.NaN
    if isinstance(x, list):
        return [f(z) for z in x]
    elif isinstance(x, float):
        return f(x)
    else:
        return "f0() accepts only float and lists of floats as parameter"
print('---')
print(f0(1.87))
print(f0(x_find))
print(f0("5"))
```

The output of the code above is:

```
---
0.93
[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]
f0() accepts only float and lists of floats as parameter
```

**FINALLY** you can also redefine f0 as f_i which is a bit complex code simulating the behavior of scipy interp1d as follows:

```
def f_i(X=[0, 1.87], Y=[1.87, 0.93], bounds_error=False):
    # ToDo: implementation of bounds_error evaluation

    def f_interpolate(u):
        assert len(X) > 1
        XY = list(zip(X, Y))
        XY.sort()

        if not (XY[0][0] <= u <= XY[-1][0]): 
            return None
        
        x_new = u
        for i in range(len(XY)-1):
            if XY[i][0] <= u <= XY[i+1][0]:
                x_lo = XY[i  ][0]
                x_hi = XY[i+1][0]
                y_lo = XY[i  ][1]
                y_hi = XY[i+1][1]
                if x_new == x_lo:
                    return y_lo
                if x_new == x_hi:
                    return y_hi
                slope = (y_hi - y_lo) / (x_hi - x_lo)
                y_new =  y_lo + slope*(x_new - x_lo)
                return y_new
        return None

    def f(v):
        assert len(X) == 1
        if v == X[0]:
            return Y[0]
        else:
            return None

    def r_f(w): 
        f_l = f_interpolate if len(X) > 1 else f
        if isinstance(w, list):
            return [f_l(z) for z in w]
        elif isinstance(w, float):
            return f_l(w)
        else:
            return "ValueErrorMessage: param. not float or list of floats"
            
    return r_f
    
y = [1.87, 1.76, 1.27, 1.185, 0.995, 0.855]
x = [ 0,    3,    6,     10,    15,    20 ]

y0 = [0.93]
x0 = [1.87]

print('---')
f = f_i(x0, y0)
print(f(1.87))

f = f_i(x, y)
x_find = [0, 5, 8, 10, 28]
print(f(x_find))
print(f("5"))
```

which gives following output:

```
---
0.93
[1.87, 1.4333333333333333, 1.2275, 1.185, None]
ValueErrorMessage: param. not float or list of floats
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. I'm sorry for not being clear. Would it be possible to modify the interpolation function of the single datapoint so that we could do just f(x_find), something similar to the one returned by `f = interp1d()`.

Comment: See my updated answer. Is it now what you asked for?

Comment: Thank you again. This helps in returning the function values i.e f0(x_find) gives `[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]`. I mean to ask if we could return a function (say, F) instead of the function values. I would then do F(x_find) to get [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]. Please let me know if I am still not clear.  What I mean is,  calling `interp1d()` returns a function and not the function values at x_find. I would like to have something similar.

Comment: See the **FINALLY** part of my answer which I am quite sure will satisfy you expectations as a start point for implementation of bounds_error evaluation and fully with `interp1d()` compatible behavior (I haven't checked out `interp1d()` myself before writing the code and let this part for completion by you yourself).

Comment: Check out the update in which there is support for actual linear interpolation. And the updated code doesn't now depend on numpy.